# How to change Visual Studio 2008 menu items color ( not the text editor but windows of VS more like skin)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, menu, themes, colors

i am working in Visual Studio 2008 and is bored of default theme of blue menu items so wanted to chage it. but so far have no clue ho to do it. found a theme editor which changes themes but this is for VS2010:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378/view/Reviews

Please note that i want to change the colour of VS menu items not the VS text editor that i know how to do it.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. VS2010 moved to WPF and thus enabled the theming support that the extension you link to uses.

Comment: I don't think you really can unless you do it for the entire OS.

Comment: ok then i am going to do it for entire OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the conclusion is that "it is not possible in VS 20008 to change skin"